# TelegramBot: Location picker button in markup keyboard, Is it possible?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Basically, In my bot, I want to send user, a reply_markup keyboard containing one button "/picklocation", a location picker should popup(default telegram location picker), I want to collect location from user. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't think that is possible.

According to the [ReplyKeyboardMarkup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardmarkup) documentation, the keyboard spec is an "Array of Array of String", equivalent to rows of buttons. When a button is tabbed, its text is sent to the bot as a text message. I don't see any way you can trigger the opening of the location picker.

Comment: yes, Only solution available is, ask user to pick location from attachments button.  I am now doing it that way.

Comment: BTW any idea how to put an telegram emoticon on keyboard button?

Comment: Emoji are simply unicode characters. I assume you can put emoji in custom keyboards the same way you put them in text messages, although I have not tried.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem by my own,
You cannot trigger location picker from markup keyboard.
What you can do is, put a picklocation button on your custom keyboard, when a user clicks on it, send him a message asking to send location from attachments button(paperclip icon in tellegram), and you will get his lat, long.

Now, telegram bot api only supports unicode. so if you want to send a emoticon to user use its UTF-8 string.

$hourglass = "\xE2\x8C\x9B"

on a keyboard button you can use smily as,

```
    $Markup = array(
    'keyboard' => 
         array($hourglass."Reschedule")
   ,'resize_keyboard' => True,'one_time_keyboard' => True
);
```

Similarly you can send emoticon o user in chat message also.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a button asking for user's location in telegram by adding another  array instead of button's text with *text* and *request_location* as it's keys.

Here is a piece of php code that does so :

```
        $keyboard = array(
                     array(array("text"=>"Button 1 that sends location","request_location"=>true)),
                      array("Button 2"),
                      array("Button 3","Button 4")
                         );

        $resp = array("keyboard" => $keyboard,
                  "resize_keyboard" => true,
                  "one_time_keyboard" => false
                 );
        $reply = json_encode($resp);
```

This is the result of code above :

[image]